# Getting the comments counter back to 0?

Tags: comments, count

I have/had 72K comments to get rid of from a site that were re-surrecting from a few years ago.  It appears the physical comments are gone but I can't get the counters to read 0.  Plus, it still says there's 72,037 pending.

Comment: Do you still have non-zero values in the comment_count column in the post table?

Comment: Counters still showing 72,037 comments. Can't find any real comments but I want the counters removed or back to '0'.  I just can't believe it is this convoluted to get this done.  What the heck is wrong with WP anyway?  I'm considering going back to an html page.

Comment: Did you check the comment count column in the wp_posts table in the database? That's where the comment count lives. What's the status of the wp_comments table, is it empty?